# Draw text with in a rect with given width

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to draw text on NSView subclass. I'm using an NSTextStorage, an NSLayoutManager, and an NSTextContainer. I followed Apple's doc and here's the method I use to calculate the necessary height for each text:

```
NSSize newSize= NSMakeSize(width, 0.0);
NSLayoutManager* layoutManager= [[textStorage layoutManagers] objectAtIndex:0];
NSTextContainer* textContainer= [[layoutManager textContainers] objectAtIndex:0];

[textContainer setContainerSize:newSize];
[textStorage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, [textStorage length])];
[textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:0.0];
[layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];

return [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size.height;
```

The only problem is that I don't know how to draw in an NSRect with the layout manager.

Can you help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was invoking this method after drawing...

Quickest topic solved ever ^^

Comment: You should mark your question as answered, even if you answered it for yourself.